# Querying custom atttributes in dll at runtime

Tags: c#, .net

I need to be able decorate a DLL with custom attributes and then read them from another app at runtime.

I have the "main" app called "QueryDLL". It queries the dll via the following code:

```
String assemblyName;
        assemblyName = @"..\GenericControl.Dll";
        Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyName);
        Type type = a.GetType("GenericControl.UserControl1", true);
        System.Reflection.MemberInfo info = type;
        var attributes = info.GetCustomAttributes(false);

        foreach (Attribute attr in attributes)
        {
          string value = attr.Name;  <----- This of course fails as attr is not of type "GenericControl.UserControl1" - How do I get access "name" field here...
        }
```

I am stumped with how to get the individual fields (such as the name field) from the attribute decoration in the dll. (I have checked other examples, but am at a loss... I suspect I am missing something simple?)

In the foreach loop above, If i turn on the debugger, and inspect the "attributes" collection, it correctly contains the 4 attribute decorations contained in the dll, but I am unable to pull out the individual fields (name, level, reviewed).

My DLL contains a class that defines the attributes:

```
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class DeveloperAttribute : Attribute
    {
        // Private fields. 
        private string name;
        private string level;
        private bool reviewed;

        // This constructor defines two required parameters: name and level. 

        public DeveloperAttribute(string name, string level)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.level = level;
            this.reviewed = false;
        }

        // Define Name property. 
        // This is a read-only attribute. 

        public virtual string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
        }

        // Define Level property. 
        // This is a read-only attribute. 

        public virtual string Level
        {
            get { return level; }
        }

        // Define Reviewed property. 
        // This is a read/write attribute. 

        public virtual bool Reviewed
        {
            get { return reviewed; }
            set { reviewed = value; }
        }
    }
```

This DLL is also decorated with this attribute:

```
 namespace GenericControl
    {

        [DeveloperAttribute("Joan Smith", "42", Reviewed = true)]
        [DeveloperAttribute("Bob Smith", "18", Reviewed = false)]
        [DeveloperAttribute("Andy White", "27", Reviewed = true)]
        [DeveloperAttribute("Mary Kline", "23", Reviewed = false)]


        public partial class UserControl1: UserControl
        {
          public UserControl1()
           {
             InitializeComponent();
            }
          ...
```

Thanks for any insight you may have...

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (Attribute attr in attributes)
{
   var devAttr = attr as DeveloperAttribute;
   if (devAttr != null)
   {
      string value = devAttr.Name;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - however I get a compile error: "Error 1 The type or namespace name 'DeveloperAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".  Which is to be expected as  DeveloperAttribute only exists in the dll.   So, if I then modify your answer and change DeveloperAttribute to GenericControl.DeveloperAttribute, each devAttr in the foreach loop is null.

Comment: @dave - Basically the problem is that the type's need to be known to both the dll and the consumer. This is where you move the Attribute type to common assembly and link it into both projects.

Comment: Just as Preet is saying, move the shared attribute to a common assembly used by both. If that is totally un-doable, then maybe you could use "dynamic" and the DLR, which will let you use the Name property. However, I think the other alterantive is safer and cleaner in this case.

Comment: @Carson63000, thank you to both of you! You both gave me a little piece of the puzzle I was missing. Casting it to DeveloperAttribute and moving the attribute definition to a common class and then referencing it. Works perfectly now. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Preet Sangha, thank you to both of you! You both gave me a little piece of the puzzle I was missing. Casting it to DeveloperAttribute and moving the attribute definition to a common class and then referencing it. Works perfectly now. Thanks guys!